projections in representation of semisimple algebras
Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional $K$-vector space and $A$ a semisimple $K$-algebra. Suppose $A=Ae_1\times \cdots  \times Ae_r$, where each $e_i$ is a centrally primitive idempotent of $A$ and suppose $M_i$ is a minimal left ideal of $A$ in $Ae_i$. Consider linear representation $\rho: A \to \text{End}_K(V)$ of $A$ into the algebra of $K$-endomorphis of $V$.
$V$ is decomposed into isotypic components $V \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^r M_i^{n_i}$ for some integers $n_i$. Is it rigorous to say $\rho(e_i)$ is a projection of $V$ onto the isotypic component $M_i^{n_i}$? or we need to say $\rho(e_i)$ is a projection of $V$ onto the subspace which is isomorphic to $M_i^{n_i}$ as $A$-module?
And how I can I rigorousley prove $$\text{image}(\rho(e_i)) \cong M_i^{n_i}$$
using the fact that $e_iM_j=0$ for $i \ne j$?

We can use that.

As you say, we have an isomorphism $V \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^r M_i^{n_i}$, and this is an isomorphism of $A$-modules, where $A$ operates on the left hand side via $\rho$ and on the right hand side via the given (left) module structure.
In particular that means, for any $j$, that $\rho(e_j) (V) \cong e_j \cdot \bigoplus_{i=1}^r M_i^{n_i} \cong e_j \cdot M_j^{n_j}$ where the second equality follows because $e_j \cdot M_i = 0$ for $i\neq j$.
Now either you know already that $e_i \cdot M_i =M_i$ (for each $i$), or you can infer it because (maybe this is the missing ingredient:) our semisimple algebra $A$ has a unit $1_A$ and $1_A = e_1+ \dots +e_r$, so $M_i= 1_A \cdot M_i = e_1M_i + \dots +e_r M_i = e_i M_i$.

$e_jM_i$ is $0$ for $i\ne j$ and $M_i$ for $i=j$,  but I feel $e_jM_i^{n_i}$ has no meaning since we require another representation from $A$ to $\text{End}_A(M_i^{n_i})$. First, I think $\rho(e_i)V \cong \rho(e_i) \bigoplus_i M_i^{n_i}$ instead of $\rho(e_i)V \cong e_i \bigoplus_i M_i^{n_i}$. How can we say $e_j M_i^{n_i}=(e_jM_i)^{n_i}$ when we have not defined action of $A$ on $M_i^{n_i}$?

If the isomorphism in the first line is an isomorphism of $A$(-left)-modules, there is an action of $A$ on both its sides. The one on the left is via $\rho$, and the one on the right, I assumed, is the "natural" one: $A$ acts on each $M_i$ via the usual left multiplication, this makes each $M_i$ into an $A$-module, and now we form their direct sum (as $A$-modules). That is what I assumed the right hand side of that iso means, and what the action on it is, which I just denoted by left multiplication.

Why can we consider the action on the right side to be the natural one? The natural action of $A$ on $M_i^{n_i}$ is given by $a\cdot (x_1,\cdots,x_{n_i})=(a\cdot x_1,\cdots, a\cdot x_{n_i})$. This means we identify $a$ with $aI_{n_i}$ matrix. but it is not necessarily true. Am I right?

When you say, "$V$ is decomposed into isotypic components $V \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^r M_i^{n_i}$ for some integers $n_i$", what is the $A$-module structure on the object on the right? I think the decomposition into isotypic components says that such an isomorphism exists, with exactly the "natural" $A$-module structure on that direct sum, and I wrote my answer under that assumption.

I think I understand. Let $\tau$ be the isomorphism from $V$ onto $\bigoplus M_i^{n_i}$. We consider $A$ acts naturally on $\bigoplus M_i^{n_i}$ via $\sigma$. Then, $\tau \circ \rho(e_i) = \sigma(e_i) \circ \tau$. So,  Image of $\rho(e_i) = \tau^{-1}(M_i^{n_i}) \cong M_i^{n_i}$. Is that what u mean?

I think one can phrase it that way, yes.
